# How to root Vivo V3?

Tags: rooting, vivo

How to root Vivo V3?

I have tried everything from using TWRP to the Magisk Patched file. I somehow did manage to get TWRP on my device but nothing else is working. I have tried around 7-8 versions of SuperSU zips but none worked. My device is becoming utterly outdated and I would be glad if anyone can help

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I've found some guides on XDA Forum: [1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/vivo-v3-root.3405884/post-69892609), [2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/vivo-v3-root.3405884/post-70044788), [3](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/vivo-v3-root.3405884/post-70098824), [4](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/vivo-v3-root.3405884/post-70116205). Since it's a long thread, consider continuing to read until the last page while trying them. If any of it works, then feel free to post the solution below!